# .Net Core Serilog SQL log to custom columns

Tags: sql, logging, asp.net-core, serilog

In a .Net Core app I added Serilog to log errors to a SQL database. If I set up everything by default and uses the standard columns, it's going fine. If I want to extend to write values to custom values, I have a problem.

The database and table were created earlier and logging is working fine, except it does not write anything in my custom column.

This is config.

```
 "WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "MSSqlServer",
    "Args": {
      "connectionString": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=WebLogging;Trusted_Connection=True;",
      "tableName": "Logs",
      "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
      "columnOptionsSection": {
        "removeStandardColumns": [ "Properties" ],
        "customColumns": [
          {
            "ColumnName": "UserName",
            "DataType": "varchar",
            "DataLength": 50
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The Properties column is still used to store data and column UserName is always empty. It writes the custom property in to the Properties column.

ILogger, which is injected in controller method.

```
 _logger.LogError("Error from .NET Core {UserName}", "Test");
```

[image]

Versions: Serilog.AspNetCore 2.1.1, Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer 5.1.2